# Jasmine + Karma tests fail at a specific test count

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Ran into a really odd issue yesterday while doing my Jasmine tests (which run headless usually, but can debug in Chrome). A test that usually passes seems to fail when I reach a specific total test count (678), but succeeds again the moment I have more than that. I reduced the number of tests such that I was only running that one test suite, and could repro the same problem at 177 tests, which I did by taking a very simple non-failing test and duplicating it a bunch more times.

I'm not seeing any other issues (i.e. a page reload error), and even stranger is that the test that supposedly fails doesn't match the line number Jasmine spits out as the offending line (which is actually the following test). When I manually step through these, it's obvious that the spy IS called, and I do believe I'm handling the async stuff correctly, as the code involves promises.

I know that isn't super specific, but I'm curious if anyone has run into this before, and has ideas for how to proceed in debugging this?

Comment: Show the test. Most likely the async stuff is not handled correctly. The number of tests just causes some specific timing state.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was probably that as well and just managed to fix it about an hour ago!

Answer (score 0):

Came to the same conclusion that Sulthan did in his comment above, but it turned out to be a problem with when I was calling my `expect`s in relation to where I was calling `done()` in some tests that involved async calls/promises. Seems like the number of tests that would run would create timing issues that finally exposed these problems.